# Cannot figure out how this jQuery code is working

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

So there is a camera taking images every couple seconds and storing those new images with new files names on the server. When a request is made to "mypage", server side the latest images are loaded up and returned in the response. The images subsequently being refreshed with this jQuery code:

```
(function($) {

    $(function() {

        var refreshInterval = 5;   // Number of seconds between image refreshes

        $('#deskshare-grid img').each(function() {
            $(this).data('src', $(this).attr('src'));
        });

        function refreshImages() {
            $.get('?r=' + Math.random(), function(response) {
                $('#deskshare-grid img').each(function(index) {
                    $(this).attr('src', $(response).find('#deskshare-grid img').eq(index).attr('src'));
                });
                setTimeout(refreshImages, refreshInterval * 1000);
            });
        }

        setTimeout(refreshImages, refreshInterval * 1000);

    });

})(jQuery);
```

The jQuery code I shared works and that is great, I didn't write the code and I want to know how it works.

My mind is stuck on the fact that a request was made for the page, the most recent image was retrieved on the server using C# and those images are included in the response. When a more recent image is created, it has a new file name.

How can jQuery refresh the photo for a file name it does not know client side?

Particularly this part of the code is confusing me:

```
$.get('?r=' + Math.random(), function(response) {
```

What is the url request for this $.get? I see the network tab of my F12 tools showing the new image responses but I do not understand how an image with a different file name could be requested with jQuery.

**UPDATE**

The accepted answer is correct but I wanted to elaborate. This jQuery is requesting the entire page again. The HTML response contains new image urls from the server. jQuery is used to parse the response, get the latest image urls and than update the existing HTML content with those new image urls parsed out of the response. This way there is no page flicker by trying to just refresh the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does get request to the same page, `Math.random()` is to make easier to view each request. When you make a request to `?` that is the same page.

Comment: Yup I was just about to post the same answer, thanks, I am allowed to accept you answer in 7 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the url request for this $.get?

The first parameter in the $.get is a relative url.  This means that the url it's trying to access will be something along the lines of www.yourdomain.com/whatever?r=.

The "?" indicates the start of a query string, the "r" is the start of the request variable and whatever follows the equal sign is the query itself.  In this particular case the query is just a randomly generated number that is sent up to the server.  Without seeing the server-side code it would appear as if the filename is generated on the client and sent up to the server in this manner, and is probably used to name the file then on the server-side then.

Answer (score 0):

The `$.get('?r=' + Math.random(), function(response) {` could be this two things:

1. Its changing the URL as a trick to not to get cached content.
2. Is server side required as dummy or something that we don't really know.

I recommend to look at the request's and response's headers for each 5'' call.